# Create Streamlit Executable

Tags: python, executable, streamlit

Is there a way to take a Streamlit app and. distribute it within the organization in the form of like a .exe file without publishing it to the web and without needing the end users to install python? I have done a ton of research and yet to truly find something that works.

Anything would be helpful!

I have also tried to design this app in Tkinter, but it uses plotly which is not supported in Tkinter sadly.

Thank you!

Comment: Check out this [feature request](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1370) on GitHub. You can upvote/comment to let Streamlit developers know you'd like them to prioritize making this easy as well as follow the various links in the discussion comments to explore options using [pyinstaller](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/using-pyinstaller-or-similar-to-create-an-executable/902/) and such to accomplish this.